# wash_out gem creates complex type with empty name

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Creating a reusable type with washout I noticed that it creates a complex type with an empty name attribute? Is there anyway around this as it seems like it generates an invalid WSDL.

```
<xsd:complexType name="">
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="universe" type="tns:universe"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="universe">
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element name="age" type="xsd:int"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Sample Code

```
  class Fluffy < WashOut::Type
  map :universe => {
        :name => :string,
        :age  => :int
      }
  end

  class FluffyContainer < WashOut::Type
    type_name 'fluffy_con'
    map :fluffy => Fluffy
  end
```

Module

```
   module soapActions
      def self.sample_request() 
       { :fluffy => Fluffy }
     end
   end
```

Controller

```
   soap_action "SampleReqest", :args => SbActions.sample_request(), :return => :string
```

This is what should I would expect it to render

```
<xsd:complexType name="universe">
    <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="age" type="xsd:int"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```